# Resize image on Ftp event

Tags: php, events, ftp

Every day in my server are copied some images via ftp.I want for every image a thumbnail to be created immediately after copying.Is there a way to catch this ftp event?Or i must check periodically for changes?
I'm on apache server using php.
Thanks

Comment: how is the ftp transfert is launched ? with a cron ? manually from an ftp client ?

Comment: @m0ntassar ftp transfer is launched with a cron but i don't have access to that code.i just have these images copied every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iNotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) which has an [PHP API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php).
So every new file added to an specific directory, you execute an script to handle that and create the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it on the FTP event? Perhaps you could defer it to when the image is first displayed

Comment: I prefer not to go that way.It's the least preferrable way.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you explain why you're against it? I use that method all the time, and witch caching I don't have a problem

Comment: Let's say i have thousands of clients that request this image every day.If i make the thumbnail existence check every time that this image is requested is an overkill since only one the first time this code will execute.